# Inplace insertion sort slower than insertion sort that creates a new list?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, insertion-sort

```
def insertion(sequence):
    for i in range(1, len(sequence)):
        key = sequence[i]
        j = search(sequence,0,i-1,key)
        while i > j:
            sequence[i], sequence[i-1] = sequence[i-1], sequence[i]
            i = i - 1
    return sequence

def insertion2(sequence):
    new_li = [sequence[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(sequence)):
        key = sequence[i]
        j = search(new_li,0,len(new_li)-1,key)
        new_li.insert(j,key)
    return new_li
```

I have 2 insertions with 2 approaches. insertion is taking significantly longer than insertion2 (5.346 as compared to 0.0313). Need help figuring out why

PS: The search is basically an auxiliary function for binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a lot more work in the first one. When you find the insertion spot, you then continually swap items to move the item from `[i]` to `[j]` In the second, you're using the `insert` function to insert an item into the second array. That just moves everything in the array down by one.

Put another way, your insertion in the first does this:

```
while i > j
    temp = sequence[i]
    sequence[i] = sequence[i-1]
    sequence[i-1] = temp
    i = i-1
```

So you do four array accesses and three assignments for every position the item has to move.

In the second one, the `insert` function does essentially this:

```
x = len(new_li)-1
while x < j
    new_li[i+1] = new_li[i]
    i = i - 1
```

Here, you do only two array accesses and one assignment for each item you have to move.

You can speed this up by writing code that copies the item to be moved into a temp variable, and a loop that is essentially the same as the second loop I showed to move things from `j` to `i` down one space, and then drop the saved item into `sequence[j]`.

Comment: Also the runtime differ on an order of 100x, shouldn't it be closer to 5/6x?

Comment: @Xuan: The large difference in running time is probably because the Python `insert` function is part of the Python runtime library, which is highly optimized.

Comment: I rewrote both of them can you take a look, the difference is still on the order of 100x. One uses array[i] = array[i-1] while the other uses insert method https://paste.pound-python.org/show/mFbilbikIZn45g79bNdT/

Comment: @Xuan If you want to verify that the difference is due to the library implementation of `insert`, replace the `insert` call with the loop I described above. That would make both versions use the `array[i] = array[i-1]`. That will make both versions use the same shifting code.